# How can I format my output

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

How can I format my output to PowerShell's script

My output looks like

> Hello @{SamAccountName=user1} is locked out
>   @{SamAccountName=user2} is locked out

My PowerShell code is

```
if ($users)   
{
        foreach($user in $users)
        {
            $message = $message + " " + $user + " is locked out" + "`r`n"
            Write-Host $user
        }
        Send-MailMessage -To $to -Subject "Locked Accounts" -BodyAsHtml $message -From $from -Credential $cred -SmtpServer $server -Debug        
}
```

Thank you

I would like my output to look like

> Hello Administrator,
>
> The following accounts are locked as of 10:31 AM on the 13th of April,
>   2015.
>
> User1 User2
>
> Thank You Automated System

As you can see in my current output, I can't figure out how to get a new line and it outputs @{SamAccountName=user1} instead of user1

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to directly access the `sAMAccountName` property on the `$user` object:

```
if ($users)   
{
        foreach($user in $users)
        {
            $message = $message + " " + $user.SamAccountName + " is locked out" + "`r`n"
        }
        Send-MailMessage -To $to -Subject "Locked Accounts" -BodyAsHtml $message -From $from -Credential $cred -SmtpServer $server -Debug        
}
```

If you wanted to make something pretty, save the user names to an array first:

```
$lockedUsers = @()
foreach($user in $users)
{
   $lockedUsers += ,$user.SamAccountName
}
```

Then you can construct your message like:

```
$message = @"
Hi Admin,

The following accounts are locked as of $(get-date)

$($lockedUsers -join ", ")

Thank you, Automated System
"@
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this approach instead.  If you use a here-string (which is depicted like so:

```
$message = @"
    So 
      this
        keeps
         track of spaces?
"@
```

You can put any amount of text inside and preserve the spacing of the message, while still having the ease of using this in your script by putting any variables inside that you might need.

As you'll see in the finished answer below, the line spacing is preserved.  I'm using the $($variableName) format to allow me to pluck out one value of an object from within a bigger string.  If I didn't use that format, the whole object would be listed, including all AD properties, which is not what we want.

```
if ($users)   
{
        $message = @"
            Hello Administrator,

            The following accounts are locked as of $((get-date).DateTime).

            $($users | select -expand SamAccountName)

            Thank You,
            Automated System
"@
        Send-MailMessage -To $to -Subject "Locked Accounts" -BodyAsHtml $message -From $from -Credential $cred -SmtpServer $server -Debug        
}
```

The message will look like this:

```
Hello Administrator,

    The following accounts are locked as of Monday, April 13, 2015 10:22:30 AM.

    localadmin Guest Stephen RDV GRAPHICS SERVICE Jim SCVMM81221tqYYJ stephen.owen krbtgt _svc_sccm azure_adfs

    Thank You,
    Automated System
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Since the Body is HTML, I used standard HTML tags when forming the strings

```
<br> = new line
<strong></strong> = bold
<font color='red'></font> = red font
```

For the account names, I did

```
 $message = $message + " " + $user.SamAccountName.ToLower() + " is locked out" + "<br>"
```